# Cannot start SweetAlert2, throw errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert2

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="module" src="sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2.min.css">
    <script type="module" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    import Swal from 'sweetalert2.js'

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Error!',
        text: 'Do you want to continue',
        type: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
    })
});
```

Both files (`test.html` and `test.js`) are in same directory!

Errors:

**Unexpected identifier** at `test.js` - line 3

**TypeError:** Cannot set property `'Sweetalert2'` of undefined - sweetalert2.js - line 8

[SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io)

Comment: Firstly, what is the error? Secondly have you checked to ensure the path to the JS files is correct?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just forgot to mention errors.

Comment: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/889#issuecomment-458733000 check this

Comment: @nivendha already checked : ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you dont need `import Swal from 'sweetalert2.js'`

**working example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sweetalert2</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'Error!',
    text: 'Do you want to continue',
    type: 'error',
    confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
  })
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```